# Trouble with Python lists

Tags: python, list

The following code is intended to dump a long list of numbers from a csv into stat_by_symbol[symbol] so that I can call the list of numbers using each symbol as a key. For some reason, the code only seems to work for the first symbol. Can someone help me fix the code to work as intended? Many thanks.

```
with open('zzdata.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    for symbol in symbols:#symbols in a list
        stat = []
        for row in reader:
            if symbol in row:
                stat.append(row[8])#stat becomes long list of numbers
        stat_by_symbol[symbol] = [stat]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can iterate over `reader` just once (therefore just the first symbol match).

Try this:

```
stat_by_symbol = {}
with open('zzdata.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        for symbol in symbols:#symbols in a list
            if symbol in row:
                stat_by_symbol.setdefault(symbol, []).append(row[8])
```

Comment: Thanks! I also need to iterate over row[8] through row[27] such that all the numbers in row[8] are in place 0, all the numbers from row[9] in place 1, and so on. I tried adding: for i in range(8, 28): ...append(row[i]), but this procedure doesn't separate the lists of numbers like I need. Any help on this?

Comment: @johnjdc - update your question and add a better example of what you need

Comment: Just posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517246/loop-to-append-multiple-lists-to-a-single-list-in-python